# How to launch aws ec2 instance using json file with python?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, python-3.5

I wrote json file for launching aws ec2 instance. I run json file in python but it was read the data in JSON. I want to execute the parameters like in instance type:t2.micro,ami id: jg85475f How to run json file in python? I request you to suggest me to execute the parameters of json file in python as soon as possible..

Comment: We'd like to help, but your question is hard to understand. Please edit your question and provide more information. For example: What do you mean by "run json file in python"? What does your JSON file contain? Are you using `boto3` commands to launch the instance? More information, please.

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help you get started with AWS automation using python with boto3

[Automating AWS With Python and Boto3](https://linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/posts/show/topic/14209-automating-aws-with-python-and-boto3)

Below is the minimal snippet(from above link) to create an ec2 instance

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-1e299d7e',
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType='t2.micro')
print instance[0].id
```

You can replace values in above code with values from JSON data.

Comment: sir, I know above code directly put the values in boto3, It was one of the dependencies of python and aws,but my requirement has all my ec2 instance data in json file, how to read and execute the data of aws in python.